# Why do Android view values differ in runtime?

Tags: android, user-interface

I'm trying to run the following unit test code snippet and it fails:

```
final TextView textView = mView.findViewById(R.id.title);
assertEquals(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_VIEW_START, textView.getTextAlignment()); // FAILS
```

The text alignment is set in the layout file like this:

```
<TextView
    ...
    android:textAlignment="viewStart" />
```

The test doesn't even succeed when I set the text alignment programmatically like this:

```
final TextView textView = mView.findViewById(R.id.title);
textView.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_VIEW_START);
assertEquals(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_VIEW_START, textView.getTextAlignment()); // STILL FAILS
```

What could be the problem? Why is the value different from the constant when I get it from the TextView object by using the getter?

I've checked what the exact int values of the two values are. TEXT_ALIGNMENT_VIEW_START is 5 but when I get the text alignment value from the TextView object I get 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because at runtime this is converted into ALIGN_LEFT or ALIGN_RIGHT, depending on the LTR of the locale.  Its not kept as VIEW_START and recalculated.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if there's any documentation available somewhere about these conversions? I'm currently facing a new similar issue but with the gravity attribute.

Comment: No, but anything START or END is generally converted.  The alternative is constantly figuring out what side its supposed to go on, which would be a large waste of resources in a view heavy app.